# weird enum usage

Tags: c, arrays, enums

As per my knowledge, enum can be used like

```
typedef enum
{
   true,
   false,
   undefined    
}FLAGS;
```

`true` and `false` can be used like

```
int a = 1;
if(a == true)
   ....
else if(a == false)
   ....
```

Coming to my issue, I came across a enum usage like,

```
FLAGS Options[] = {true, undefined};
```

i.e array is declared of type enum. I have no idea. Please clarify me.

Edit:: What will happen in the mentioned scenario.

prinf("\n true:%d, false:%d, undefined:%d\n", true, false, undefined);

true: 0, false:1, undefined: 2

why?

**Edit 2::**
How it differs with `int Options[] = {true, undefined};`

Comment: About *what exactly* don't you have any idea?

Comment: Options is an array of two values of type FLAGS.

Comment: Would you mind giving further explanation ?

Comment: using enum as array. what it will do in this mentioned case.

Comment: `Options[0]` is `true`. `Options[1]` is `undefined`.

Comment: @H2CO3 And then what ? Isn't this what OP is trying to understand ?

Comment: `int Options[]` and `FLAGS Options[]` only differ in the type of the array. Both are allowed, as enum values are convertible to `int`. *(But note that having `true==0` and `false==1` will confuse everyone, because normally it is the other way around)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `enum` is just like an integer type, with the added bonus of having a bunch of named literals. There's nothing stopping you from declaring an array of enumerated values, it's basically just an array of integers.

Answer (score 2):

That code is perectly fine. You can make an array of any type -- here you declared an array of two elements, each of which is of type `enum FLAGS`.

Edit: you seem to be confused about the meaning of "undefined". It's *not* technically an undefined value, nor a reserved keyword in C. Thar's just 2 in this case.

> What will happen in the mentioned scenario.

```
prinf("\n true:%d, false:%d, undefined:%d\n", true, false, undefined);
```

This will print the following:

```
true:0, false:1, undefined:2
```